# How to make .pyw identically behave like .py: redirect output, input and error?

Tags: python, windows, console, subprocess

The question would be: How can I make `.pyw` behave like the same way as `.py` script?

Not sure if this is possible, after blindly looking around on multiple examples.

The description of expected behaviour on a Windows Operating System:

1. When you open a command prompt and launch a `.py` file, the output of the `print()` is printed in the command prompt. This is clearly not what happens when launching `.pyw` script. No output is delivered to the command prompt.
2. When double clicking the `.py` file, the command prompt is opened and the output is being captured. `.pyw` file on the other hand does not open a command prompt, it is windowless.

These are my main observations right now.

In the end.
I expect for when opening`.pyw`: the **input**, **output** and **error** to be directed to the command prompt where it was opened from. If there is no command prompt - open the command prompt and redirect everything to it, the same way it happens when running a regular `.py` script.